# Android :Launching Iperf as separate process

Tags: android, networking, process

Hi I am using iperf to test the Network throughput, for that i am creating the executable of the iperf c code using NDK, and i am successfully able to launch the process as follows:

```
 Process process ;
 process = new ProcessBuilder().command(commandList).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
```

but my concern is that in case my application crashes at some point (As such there is no crash, but in case it crashes )then the external process keeps on running ,so i need a way to destroy this process at any point of time from any activity or service.
So in case someone has some idea please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the usual solution in JVM land is to use `Runtime.addShutdownHook` but the Android version carries this warning:

> Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that your code is run. Instead, you should use the most appropriate lifecycle notification (Activity.onPause, say).

Since you care about crashes, you can set the uncaught exception handler on any thread that might crash to also kill the child process (look up `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`).

Apart from that, if you know the PID, you can use `kill` to send a signal (since we don't have pkill) . You can try to do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -SIGINT <PID-goes-here>");`

If you don't have a PID, Android's standard image comes with a version of `ps` but unfortunately it's unclear what syntax it supports, so I'd suggest parsing its output instead. (Also, the fact that it's in the base image leads me to believe that OEM builds would have it too).

But yes, this is an unnecessarily difficult way to stop a process. It's just the price you have to pay for using something JVM-ish - you're supposed to build JNI bridges, not start external processes.